# PHP (nível de permissão no servidor)

Tags: php, apache

Criei uma aplicação em php que faz uploads de arquivos (PDF, imagens e JSON) que funciona corretamente no meu servidor PHP 5.2.17, porém no servidor do cliente, a aplicação só funciona se eu mudar a permissão da pasta do site para 777.

No meu servidor eu uso 755 para as pastas e 644 para os arquivos e tudo funciona corretamente, não existem erros na aplicação no meu servidor, eu uso move upload para fazer a carga dos arquivos.

Alguém tem pistas sobre o que pode estar aconntecendo?

Comment: Talvez alguma configuração do OS ou do servidor do cliente, já tentou reinstalar o lamp/wamp/xampp?

Comment: Provavelmente os grupos/usuários são diferentes. Utilize `ls -ahl /path/to` ou `ll /path/to` para verificar o usuário e o grupo ao qual pertence os arquivos.

Comment: "_Alguém tem pistas sobre o que pode estar aconntecendo?_".. acontecendo oq?

Comment: – dvd o upload de arquivos não funciona no nível normal de permissão. Isso não ficou claro? O upload só acontece quando eu mudo a permissão da pasta do site para 777, o que é contra o padrão estipulado pelo cliente.

Comment: A permissão 755  vai dar permissão de gravação apenas para o dono da pasta. Normalmente quem faz isto é o apache. Você precisa dar permissão para o usuário apache do grupo apache: `chown apache:apache -R /pasta/de/upload`